# What is more pythonic: trivial lambda or None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

When a function accepts a function argument (or a class has a function slot), there is a choice between two approaches:

```
def foo(..., my_func=None, ...):
    ...
    if my_func:
        my_func(...)
    ...
```

and

```
def foo(..., my_func=(lambda ...: None), ...):
    ...
    my_func(...)
    ...
```

What is more Pythonic/clear/readable?

What is faster - an extra boolean check or a trivial function call?

Comment: `x is not None` is probably faster than `(lambda:None)()` of course, this is pretty trivial to check for yourself.. . I prefer the None check (using `is`) over the default lambda for readability reasons, and it's a common Python idiom

Comment: I think it really depends on what the rest of your code is doing. Cannot really tell without a slightly more concret example

Comment: Totally agree with @OlivierMelançon depending on an actual situation our assumptions may shift.

Comment: I tend to like using `None` as a default argument because callers don't have to think about how to enable the default behavior -- just use `None`. If the default argument is something other than `None`, then to get the default behavior, a caller *mustn't* specify the argument (or must know its default value).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: you seem to disagree with the only answer provided ATM. Does this mean that there is no consensus?! ;-)

Comment: I think here the first is more readable so perhaps better. If you need some kind of chaining then it will be better to retain it as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using this:

```
>>> def bar():
...     print("Goodbye, World!")
...
```

I find this very readable:

```
>>> def foo(my_func = lambda : None):
...     my_func()
...
>>> foo()
>>> foo(bar)
Goodbye, World!
```

I find this pointlessly annoying

```
>>> def baz(my_func = None):
...     if my_func is not None:
...         my_func()
...
>>> baz()
>>> baz(bar)
Goodbye, World!
```

Try to keep None checks out of your life. Use None when you want it to do what it does well: blow up in your face. Don't ask it to be quiet. One way or another it's going to create annoying noise if you use it.

> What is faster - an extra boolean check or a trivial function call?

Why, in Gods name, do you care?

---

For the record, I find this readable but overly permissive:

```
>>> def buz(my_func = lambda **k:None):
...     my_func()
...
>>> buz(bar)
Goodbye, World!
```

Comment: How about there are some args needed to pass into the function? The lambda function should be `lambda *args, **kwargs: None`. Isn't it also annoying?

Comment: Nope. `def foo(my_func = lambda x: None): my_func("cruel world!")`

Comment: But this is not the only situation, if `my_func`'s signature is `my_func(a, b, c, d=xxx, e=xxx)`. Then you have to write a general lambda as I give.

Comment: @Sraw You are confusing what the function allows with how I use it. I only have to publish how I use it. If I pass three args to my_func then my lambda need only ask for three arg functions. If your function can handle my three args then it fits my three arg lambda regardless of how many optionals it has.

Comment: Um... I am really confused. I mean, sometimes you cannot determine how many args does `my_func` need in advance. Or sometimes you have multiple different `foo` which accepts different `my_func`, so you need to write different lambda functions for each `foo`. Or you can write an ultimate one to fit all situation `lambda *args, **kwargs: None`.

Comment: If it doesn't need what I'm going to give it then it's never going to work anyway. I'm not writing code to use every function ever. I'm writing code that doesn't care what function it uses so long as it works with what I give it. My code is not going to make up new arguments to pass just because the function you pass me demands it. Do that and you deserve the error you get.